# Is there any function that can increase blur on Textfield background when selected? TVOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I have a textfield and I want to increase the blur opacity when textfield is being focus, I am not sure if there are a build in function for me to change the background of  blur opacity in TVOS.[image]

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UITextFieldDelegate** method **textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)** to change textfield opacity. **UITextFieldDelegate** is available in **tvOS**. Set textfield delegate to viewcontroller

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField:UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self

}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.alpha = 1
    return true
}
```